# how to make php artisan command available?

Tags: laravel

I read previous posts here about same problem but they did not solve my problem. I am running wamp latest version on windows 7 and I cloned a laravel app from github then I ran `composer install` on the root folder of the app and all vendors installed. however I still can not execute `php artisan list` on the app root folder

I tried also this command

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

but same problem also there is no laravel folder installed inside vendor folder. I dont know what laravel version used with this web app

So how I can make `php artisan` work ?

Update:

I opened composer.json file and I found no Laravel frame work to install !! should I return to the developer who made this or I just add Laravel package to composer.json and run composer install again ? if so what I should add to the composer.json ? I dont know which version to install !!

Comment: what output are you seeing when running the command?

Comment: Could not open input file: artisan

Comment: If you run `ls` or `dir` on Windows, do you see the `artisan` file?

Answer (score 1):

Your project has to have an `artisan` file in the root directory, otherwise the `php artisan` command won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Fixed it by using the following command, which results in a clean installation.

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel my-project
```

If errors occur, your CLI will show them.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation#installation)